# What's wrong with my sqlite query?

Tags: sqlite

trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong in this sqlite query.

```
SELECT count(id),player,matchId
FROM Goals
GROUP BY matchId,player
WHERE Goals > 2;
```

Edit: Figured out what was wrong, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You have inside your `Goals` table a column named `Goals`?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Does the table `Goals` have a column called `Goals`?

Comment: No, that was incorrect of me, however it's not fitting and gives me the error message  near "GROUP": Syntax error.

Comment: Start by posting real code. And include the error in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Goals` is a table.  You can't compare it to a number.  How about:

```
SELECT count(id), player, matchId
FROM Goals
GROUP BY matchId, player
HAVING count(id) > 2;
```

In addition:

- To handle aggregation functions, use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.
- You should put the aggregation columns in the same order in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  Just be neat.
- You could use a column alias if you liked, but you don't have one for the count.

Comment: I get an error saying that near "GROUP": Syntax error.

Comment: @J.A.R.E.D . . . The syntax is fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a7567.

Answer (score 1):

`where` goes before `group by`

```
SELECT count(id),player,matchId
FROM Goals
WHERE Goals > 2
GROUP BY matchId,player
```